# Can words be removed from language? Are there examples of such?

Tags: dictionaries

My research has shown that lexicographers typically look to determine whether a word is currently widely used and whether there is a gap by no alternative being available before it being considered for usage in dictionaries.

On the other side of this, is anyone aware of words that have been removed from the English dictionary based on the same criteria?

Comment: "Can be" or "should be"?

Comment: While removals are not as widely publicized as additions, a simple web search turns up [various](https://www.newyorker.com/books/page-turner/panic-dictionary) [reports](https://slate.com/culture/2011/08/concise-oxford-english-dictionary-what-words-got-dropped-to-make-room-for-woot-noob-nurdle-mankini-and-jeggings.html) of words being removed from general reference dictionaries because they have fallen out of use. What has your own research found thus far?

Answer (score 3):

There is no single "English Dictionary".  A simplified dictionary or a learners' dictionary that has only commonly-used words will certainly have new words added and old-fashioned ones removed from time to time. However a comprehensive dictionary such as the *Oxford English Dictionary* https://www.oed.com/ only gets bigger as time goes on and new words come into use.

Comment: May need to be edited to consider [archaic words listing of Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/archaic-words/). It's not clear whether these are ever removed from the above...

Answer (score 2):

Have you heard any of these words: "ambassade", "latrant", or "princox"? Despite all of them occurring in [Samuel Johnson's 1755 dictionary](https://johnsonsdictionaryonline.com/), it's very likely you haven't. If listed in dictionaries (they aren't in [NOAD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Oxford_American_Dictionary)), you will see them listed as *archaic*, which means that nobody really uses them anymore. In other words, they have essentially been removed from the language. As you go back further and further in time you'll see more and more words like this, especially with [Old English](http://www.oereader.ca/glos.htm).

As for whether dictionaries remove words, that depends on the dictionary. For print dictionaries, the answer is almost always yes, words are removed. The notable exception was the Oxford English Dictionary, when it was in print, because it is, in part, a historical dictionary. In addition, online dictionaries don't tend to remove words, since there's not much cost and some potential benefit to keeping them. The policies for adding/removing words for both the OED and Oxford's main online dictionary can be found [here](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/news-and-press/oxford-dictionaries-faq). In contrast, see [this article](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2015/01/15/decide-words-include-childrens-dictionaries/) to see their philosophy about their printed children's dictionary and [this article](https://slate.com/culture/2011/08/concise-oxford-english-dictionary-what-words-got-dropped-to-make-room-for-woot-noob-nurdle-mankini-and-jeggings.html) for a discussion of what words they removed from the Oxford Concise English Dictionary (every year it's discussed because people get upset about it).

Comment: Hi Laurel. That's exactly what I was looking for. Really appreciate the answer.